# How much does mass center of satellite oscillates about elliptic orbit as its spinning around the Earth?

Tags: orbital-motion, estimation, error-analysis, celestial-mechanics, satellites

I would like to know how much the real orbit of satellite can differ to the elliptic one.

Some perturbation of mass center position of the satellite must occur - Earth gravity accelaration changes as it is not a perfect ball. We can also take into account influence of varying gravitational force from secondary bodies - the moon or the sun. Collisions with cosmic debris or particles in the thermosphere or exosphere can also perturbate elliptic orbit of satellite.

Alas, I cant find information about such a perturbation of mass center displacement of orbiting satellite.

In particular I would like to know how to measure or estimate the amplitude of deviation from the elliptic orbit of satellite center of mass as its spinning around the planet at the period of one cycle.
Let's say  satellite would have a mass like  1000 kg, length like 100m and it spins at the height of ISS. What value of such an amplitude can I expect?

Comment: Not a complete answer: consider also that some of these things causes phenomena that are forbidden in the case of orbiting a perfectly spherical body. For example the oblateness of the earth causes inclined satellite orbits to precess (move along the equator a tiny bit after each orbit) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nodal_precession

Comment: And $g$ is not a constant with respect to position - it varies because of density variations over and above the oblateness.

Comment: @AndrewChristensen -thank you for this link. But I see If I get inclination of zero this nodal precession won't take place. What about 3 body problem - does the Moon have measurable impact on change of the satellite position?

Comment: @lodzki Absolutely it does - it helps that satellite orbits are studied to very high precision over very long periods of time. But note that the earth is already in "free fall" around the moon, so it's not like orbits will simply be shifted toward the moon. On the other hand, the tidal effect of the moon will cause orbits to be a few meters closer to the center of the earth when they are in a position that forms a 90 degree angle between the earth and the moon.

Comment: @JonCuster - can't we assume that the Earth has homogenous density for every ellipsoid surface at given relative height from the center of the planet? I mean as the Earth was forming it was one big "fireball" and all the matter was liquified or gaseous. So due to gravitational convection heavy particles must be in general deeper than the lighter ones. So gradient of density should have direction of Earth's radius?

Comment: @JonCuster is pointing out another kind of perturbation of satellite orbits from perfect ellipsoids. Which is that the surface of the earth has different acceleration due to gravity in different places based on the local bedrock-rock type, nearby mountains, etc. Of course, as a rough approximation you can ignore this. On the moon this effect is even worse - fun fact, there are only 4 different orbit paths near the surface of the moon which are stable. On any other orbit path the spaceship will eventually crash into the surface because of these small perturbations.

Comment: @AndrewChristensen Thank you.